# Wicket CheckBoxMultipleChoice doesn't update

Tags: java, ajax, wicket

My wicket panel is requiring at least two clicks to update either of the CheckBoxMulitpleChoice components using the onSubmit method of my buttons.  How can I get these components to update on the first click?

I am using two CheckBoxMultipleChoice components to compile a list of users to notify.  The first is populated based on users available in a DropDownChoice team selection.  The user may then select users from that team to add to the second CheckBoxMultipleChoice, which displays all of the users to notify and allows the user to remove users.

I have tried using the Palette component but am using wicket 1.3.1 (which I am having troubles migrating to 1.4, but that is for another post) and have not been successful in controlling the UI.  I have also tried placing the components in forms, but this has not changed the functionality.  It requires at least 2 clicks to either add or remove an entry from the checkbox.  it appears that the getValue() is not updating until after the button behavior has been performed.

```
        // Team selection for notification =================================
        final DropDownChoice teamNotificationChoice = new DropDownChoice("teamNotification", teamList, new IChoiceRenderer() {
            public Object getDisplayValue(Object o) {
                return ((Team) o).getName();
            }
            public String getIdValue(Object o, int i) {
                return Long.toString(((Team) o).getId());
            }
        });
        notifySelectionList.add(teamNotificationChoice);

        // teamUser selection list for notification ========================
        List<ItemUser> choices = UserUtils.convertToItemUserListFromUsers(getJtrac().findUsersForSpace(space.getId()));
        teamUsers = new CheckBoxMultipleChoice("teamUsers", choices, new IChoiceRenderer() {
            public Object getDisplayValue(Object o) {
                return ((ItemUser) o).getUser().getName();
            }
            public String getIdValue(Object o, int i) {
                return ((ItemUser) o).getUser().getLoginName();
            }
        });
        notifySelectionList.add(teamUsers);

        // Add selected teamUsers button ===================================
        Button button = new Button("addUsersToList") {
            @Override
            public void onSubmit(){
            }
        };
        button.add(new AjaxFormComponentUpdatingBehavior("onClick") {
            protected void onUpdate(AjaxRequestTarget target) {
                List choices = teamUsers.getChoices();
                String value = teamUsers.getValue();
                for (int index = 0; index < choices.size(); index++) {
                    final ItemUser choice = (ItemUser) choices.get(index);
                    if(isSelected(choice, index, value)&!userSelection.contains(choice)) {
                        userSelection.add(choice);
                    }
                }
                SortUtils.sortItemUsers(userSelection);
                itemUsers.setChoices(userSelection);
                target.addComponent(itemUsers);
            }
        });
        notifySelectionList.add(button);
        notifySelectionList.setOutputMarkupId(true);

        // notify list ===================================================
        itemUsers = new CheckBoxMultipleChoice("itemUsers", userSelection, new IChoiceRenderer() {
            public Object getDisplayValue(Object o) {
                return ((ItemUser) o).getUser().getName();
            }
            public String getIdValue(Object o, int i) {
                return ((ItemUser) o).getUser().getLoginName();
            }
        });
        itemUsers.setMaxRows(10);
        itemUsers.setOutputMarkupId(true);
        notifyList.setOutputMarkupId(true);
        notifyList.add(itemUsers);

        // Remove selected teamUsers button ===================================
        Button removeButton = new Button("removeUsersFromList") {
            @Override
            public void onSubmit(){
            }
        };
        removeButton.add(new AjaxFormComponentUpdatingBehavior("onClick") {
            protected void onUpdate(AjaxRequestTarget target) {
                List choices = itemUsers.getChoices();
                String value = itemUsers.getValue();
                for (int index = 0; index < choices.size(); index++) {
                    final ItemUser choice = (ItemUser) choices.get(index);
                    if(isSelected(choice, index, value)) {
                        userSelection.remove(choice);
                    }
                }
                itemUsers.setChoices(userSelection);
                target.addComponent(itemUsers);
            }
        });
        notifyList.add(removeButton);
```

Thank you in advance for any advice you may be able to offer...

Comment: Upgrade to something newer. 1.3.1 is very old version.

Comment: @martin-g did you read my post?  The issue is not related to the version.  It ended up being my overuse of AjaxFormComponentUpdatingBehavior().

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I don't know if anyone cares, since I did not get any feedback I suppose this is not a common problem, but I will put my solution here just in case it can help someone.

I was able to get it worked out by dropping the `AjaxFormComponentUpdatingBehavior()` and just using the `onSubmit()` method of the buttons.  I also `setDefaultFormProcessing(false)` on the buttons so that only the `CheckboxMultipleChoice` panels would be updated.  It now looks as follows:

```
        // Team selection for notification =================================
        final DropDownChoice teamNotificationChoice = new DropDownChoice("teamNotification", teamList, new IChoiceRenderer() {
            public Object getDisplayValue(Object o) {
                return ((Team) o).getName();
            }
            public String getIdValue(Object o, int i) {
                return Long.toString(((Team) o).getId());
            }
        });
        notifySelectionList.add(teamNotificationChoice);

        // teamUser selection list for notification ========================
        List<ItemUser> choices = UserUtils.convertToItemUserListFromUsers(getJtrac().findUsersForSpace(space.getId()));
        teamUsers = new JtracCheckBoxMultipleChoice("teamUsers", choices, new IChoiceRenderer() {
            public Object getDisplayValue(Object o) {
                return ((ItemUser) o).getUser().getName();
            }
            public String getIdValue(Object o, int i) {
                return ((ItemUser) o).getUser().getLoginName();
            }
        });
        notifySelectionList.add(teamUsers);

        // Add selected teamUsers button ===================================
        Button button = new Button("addUsersToList") {
            @Override
            public void onSubmit(){
                List choices = teamUsers.getChoices();
                String value = teamUsers.getValue();
                for (int index = 0; index < choices.size(); index++) {
                    final ItemUser choice = (ItemUser) choices.get(index);
                    if(isSelected(choice, index, value)&!userSelection.contains(choice)) {
                        userSelection.add(choice);
                    }
                }
                SortUtils.sortItemUsers(userSelection);
                itemUsers.setChoices(userSelection);
                notifyList.add(itemUsers);
                teamUsers.updateModel();
            }
        };
        button.setDefaultFormProcessing(false);
        notifySelectionList.add(button);
        notifySelectionList.setOutputMarkupId(true);

        // notify list ===================================================
        itemUsers = new JtracCheckBoxMultipleChoice("itemUsers", userSelection, new IChoiceRenderer() {
            public Object getDisplayValue(Object o) {
                return ((ItemUser) o).getUser().getName();
            }
            public String getIdValue(Object o, int i) {
                return ((ItemUser) o).getUser().getLoginName();
            }
        });
        itemUsers.setMaxRows(10);
        itemUsers.setOutputMarkupId(true);
        notifyList.setOutputMarkupId(true);
        notifyList.add(itemUsers);

        // Remove selected teamUsers button ===================================
        Button removeButton = new Button("removeUsersFromList") {
            @Override
            public void onSubmit(){
                List choices = itemUsers.getChoices();
                String value = itemUsers.getValue();
                if(value!=""){
                    String[] valueList = itemUsers.getValue().split(";");
                    List<User> userList = new ArrayList<User>();
                    for (String s:valueList){
                        userList.add(getJtrac().loadUser(s));
                    }
                    List<ItemUser> itemUserList = UserUtils.convertToItemUserListFromUsers(userList);
                    for (ItemUser iu:itemUserList) {
                        userSelection.remove(iu);
                    }
                    itemUsers.setChoices(userSelection);
                    notifyList.add(itemUsers);
                }
            }
        };
        removeButton.setDefaultFormProcessing(false);
        notifyList.add(removeButton);
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing your answer. I have similar problem, but is basically the CheckboxMultipleChoice only brings the values the first time the Button is clicked, then I display some errors that depends on the values selected, after correcting the error, the Model related to the CheckboxMultipleChoice  element will not update again :(

Comment: @will824 - I am not sure about your particular configuration, but you could possibly try performing an ajax refresh of your checkbox when you are displaying the errors?  If you post your own question with some code, I can see if I have any ideas that can help.  Thanks.